# MySQL sum of counts of two queries

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I am (very) new to MySQL.  Forgive my lack of knowledge....

I am working on a hockey stat database where I need to add all the assists and all the goals together to get "total points".  I have two queries already figured out, but I am not able to figure out how to sum the two.
Here are the queries:

```
select player_id, count(*) 
from(select * from 1st_assists
union
select * from 2nd_assists) as tem
join players on tem.fk_player_id=players.player_id
group by fk_player_id
order by count(*) desc

select player_id, count(*)
from goals_for
join shots_for on goals_for.fk_shot_for_id=shots_for.shot_for_id
join players on shots_for.fk_player_id=players.player_id
group by player_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

how do I combine these two queries into one and get the total of both counts?

Here are the results of each of the queries

```
Total Assists
player_id   count(*)
79      24
55      22
45      17
90      16
40      15
65      15
37      13
1       13
20      11
84      11
64      10
27      9
93      7
8       5
24      3
57      1

Goals
player_id   count(*)
90      38
37      28
40      19
55      13
45      11
1       8
24      8
20      8
84      8
27      6
8       5
79      4
65      4
93      1
64      1
```

Comment: DO you want to get the total count for each player?

Comment: yes, that is right.  Total for each player.

Comment: does all players appear in both of your queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is untested, but can you, please, try this:

```
select p.player_first_name, p.player_last_name, (count1+count2) as total_count
from
(select player_id, count(*) count1
from(select * from 1st_assists
union
select * from 2nd_assists) as tem
join players on tem.fk_player_id=players.player_id
group by fk_player_id
order by count(*) desc) q1
left join
(select player_id, count(*) count2
from goals_for
join shots_for on goals_for.fk_shot_for_id=shots_for.shot_for_id
join players on shots_for.fk_player_id=players.player_id
group by player_id) q2
ON q1.player_id=q2.player_id
left join player p ON q1.player_id=p.player_id
order by (count1+count2) desc;
```

Comment: That looks like it worked!!  How do I sort desc by total_points?  I tried a couple things and didn't work...

Comment: nevermind, I had a bonehead syntax error.  All good.  Now if I could only figure out how you did it.  Might take me some time to stare at it...Thanks so much, you answered in just over 10 minutes.  I should have asked the question 12 hours ago!!

Comment: So, is everything ok with the query? I only has joined these two queries on the player_id column, and then added the counts provided by each subquery.

Comment: See edit for the ordering by total count in descending order.

Comment: what if I want to replace the player id with player_first_name and player_last_name name?